# Windows Server 2008 Super Slow

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am on Windows Server 2008 OS Std, 32 bit. It started to slow down yesterday around 3pm. Opening files, restarting OS, opening any applications takes more then 5 minutes. then it started to work fine by 9 pm.

Now today again around 1 pm, it started to slow down....same issue as yesterday.

Things that I have tried.

Disconnected from Network totally.

Checked CPU & RAM usage within Task manager, and all is good.

Stoped the Word Wide Web Service to STOP IIS from serving sites.

Checked the event log, but could not find anything, unless i dont know where to look?

Comment: Since you said restarting the OS is slow, it could be a failing disk. Whats your disk configuration like, is RAID in use?

Comment: And what is safe mode like? Any different?

Comment: I'm with John.  I've seen RAID 5 with a dying disk seize up and become unresponsive during backups, for example.

Comment: its a staging server with a simple single  SATA HDD.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace the disk as soon as possible, as it sounds like it could be failing. Since you have a single SATA disk, I hope you have a backup somewhere. The process of reading all data from the existing disk could cause it to fail completely and you could have an even bigger problem on your hands.

Comment: is it normal for HDD to be dead slow and then be normal again?

Comment: @highwingers Anything could happen, depending on what areas of the disk are being accessed etc. The thing is, its not slowing down at the same time each day. By the sounds of it, your restarts are slow too which suggests a hardware issue.

Comment: I just swap RAM stick...its working fine, i will wait until tomorrow to check what happens.

Comment: @highwingers. Sounds like you're in the right track, what prompted you to swap the ram out. Did you do a memtest?

Answer (score 0):

To got back to the basics:

Did anything change?

New software installation?

Are there any server apps installed in addition to the standard installs (ie. Exchange)?

Is there potentially a dramatic load increase midday?